# Cypher: loop over properties and count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a lot of nodes, containing the property `gender`. Possible values for `gender` are: *male*, *female* and *andy*. I am looking for a cypher query, that will return the count of each value. For example...

```
"male"   100
"female" 132
"andy"   12
```

The solution should also work for nodes with a property with more than three cases, eg. names, and the number of persons with the name.

Comment: I don't understand the second requirement: `The solution should also work for nodes with a property with more than three cases, eg. names, and the number of persons with the name.`  Can you please provide an example?

Comment: it was just to make clear that it should work with n values for the property.. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This very simple query will return a count of every distinct `gender` value. You can do the same thing for any property with any number of possible values.

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n.gender, COUNT(*)
```

You should modify the `MATCH` clause to specifically pick nodes that actually have the property you are counting. (Any matched nodes that do not have that property would also be counted, with a value of `null` -- and appear in the results.)